# White space at beginning of string taken from a Json (Angular 2+)

Tags: arrays, json, angular, object

So, the case is the following (i'm going to simplify the code so it's more readable but the same case):

i have a json file in a url (say "http://localhost:3000")with information like this:

```
{
  "Object1":{
    "a":"Lorem ipsum dolor",
    "b":"Sit amet consectetur"},

  "Object2":{
    "a":"Lorem ipsum dolor",
    "b":"Sit amet consectetur"}
}
```

and a service to get this data

getData.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';


@Injectable()
export class GetDataService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  private jsonURL: string = "http://localhost:3000/Object1"

  getData() {

      return (this.http.get(this.jsonURL).map((response:Response)=>response.json()))
  }

}
```

and a component like this one

component1.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GetDataService } from './services/getData.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component1',
  templateUrl: './component1.component.html',
})
export class Component1Component implements OnInit {

  data = [] 

  constructor(private getDataService: GetDataService,
              ) { }

 ngOnInit() {

    const  GetDataService  = this.getDataService.getData().subscribe(data => this.data= data);

  }
```

and an html template

component1.component.hml:

```
<p>{{data.a}}</p>
```

the case is that the string "Lorem ipsum dolor" renders like "---Lorem ipsum dolor" (the dashes are white spaces in my view) and i don't know why this happens or how to solve it.

Comment: can you post the component1.html

Comment: the real one is pretty big (actually 426 code lines) and would not be understood, but the simple <p></p> tag with the data binding inside is the exact case of what is inside that component and is giving me some trouble.

Comment: okay try to log it on the console not render it in the DOM to make sure that there are 3 spaces

Comment: Did you check that the spaces are inside the p tag, and not coming from previous tag?